# Why are methods of igraph.Graph neither "pickle-able" nor "dill-able"?

Tags: python, igraph

Why isn't it possible to serialize methods of `igraph.Graph` with pickle or dill? Both approaches yield a `PicklingError`.

Example:

```
import igraph, dill, pickle

pickle.dumps(igraph.Graph.degree)
dill.dumps(igraph.Graph.degree)
```

Here, both calls of `dumps` end with an exception:

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
...
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'igraph.Graph'>: it's not the same object as igraph.Graph
```

Creating a wrapper function like that one shown below is a possible workaround, but this doesn't explain the initial problem.

```
def degree_wrapper(graph, *args, **kwargs):
    return graph.degree(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there another way to make dill work for those cases?

fyi:
python-igraph==0.7.1.post6; dill==0.2.5; Python 3.4.3+ (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:03:50) [GCC 5.2.1 20151010]; Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is specific to igraph; the documentation of the `pickle` module lists the objects that can be pickled:

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - None, True, and False
> - integers, long integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> - normal and Unicode strings
> - tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> - functions defined at the top level of a module
> - built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes whose `__dict__` or the result of calling `__getstate__()` is picklable (see section The pickle protocol for details).

The `degree` method of the `Graph` class does not fit any of the categories above. Your function does, because it is (presumably) defined at the top level of a module.

As for `dill`, I have no idea, but since it is built on `pickle`, it can be assumed that the same limitations also apply to `dill`.